# Batch file, check if string contains another string with special characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will append some items to the proxy exceptions list.

I've currently got this:-

```
echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride') do set "var=%%b"

set "devlocal=;*.dev.local;"
set "local=*.local;"

set "exceptions=%var%%devlocal%%local%"

echo "%exceptions%"

pause

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "%exceptions%" /f

pause
```

This runs okay. But what I want to do is firstly check to see if `*.dev.local` already exists in the exceptions and if so do NOT add it in. The same for `*.local`.

I cant seem to use `FINDSTR` as it doesent support special characters such as `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to add terms if they don't exist.
It's not efficient but for two terms it will work fine.

```
echo "%var%"|findstr /L /i "*.dev.local" >nul || set "var=%var%;*.dev.local;"
echo "%var%"|findstr /L /i "*.local"     >nul || set "var=%var%;*.local"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the strings with an empty string:

```
echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride') do set "var=%%b"

set "devlocal=;*.dev.local;"
set "local=*.local;"

REM SET %v:str1=str2% returns the value of variable v in which all occurrences of str1 are replaced by str2
REM Note that we use an empty string in place of str2
SET var=%var:;*.dev.local;=%
SET var=%var:*.local;=%

set "exceptions=%var%%devlocal%%local%"

echo "%exceptions%"

pause

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "%exceptions%" /f

pause
```

Comment: Sure i tried something like this. Get `syntax is incorrect`. Im sure its because it cant handle the `*.dev.local` in `SET var=%var:;*.dev.local;=%`

Comment: It simply works for me. Have you disabled the command extensions?